# Display SVG image with Foundation Image component

Tags: java, svg, aem, javax.imageio

I am trying to use the Image component in CQ5.6 to include an SVG image on a page.  I can get the component to use the SVG by dragging the image from the content finder to the component, but this also causes an error in the log:

```
Caused by: javax.imageio.IIOException: No decoder available to load the image
    at com.day.image.Layer.<init>(Layer.java:786)
    at com.day.image.Layer.<init>(Layer.java:588)
    at com.day.image.Layer.<init>(Layer.java:511)
    at com.day.cq.commons.ImageHelper.createLayer(ImageHelper.java:173)
    at com.day.cq.commons.ImageResource.getLayer(ImageResource.java:569)
    at libs.foundation.components.parbase.img_GET.writeLayer(img_GET.java:72)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.commons.AbstractImageServlet.doGet(AbstractImageServlet.java:80)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:268)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.java.impl.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:126)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.java.impl.JavaScriptEngineFactory.callServlet(JavaScriptEngineFactory.java:211)
    ... 88 more
```

I've made several attempts to add support for SVGs by including SVG implementations of the `javax.imageio`, but have yet to succeed.  The closest that I have come to success was using Batik, in which case CQ5 seemed to get stuck in an infinite loop at `Layer.java:769-781`.

Has anybody managed to make the OOTB Image component work with SVG images?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar problem. I don't even care if I use the default component, but for the life of me I can't get AEM to serve an SVG without either complaining about the decoder or serving with `Content-Disposition: attachment`. See: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2496887

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem. I tried to download the file manually from CRX and opening that in my default image viewer. Unfortunately, my default image viewer also gave the same error.

For me the problem was with uploading part of that image. My InputStream passed in [JCRUtil.put](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html) skipped some bytes to write because I used [TikaInputStream](https://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/io/TikaInputStream.html) before writting for validating the mediaType of the uploaded file.